# Fireabse login con Google y Facebook

Tags: android, firebase, google-api, autenticación

Por alguna extraña razón cuando creo un usuario ya sea por **Google** o por **Facebook** el ***providerId*** que me devuelve la instancia de **FirebaseUser** me dice que es ***Firebase*** y no ninguno de los anteriores. Para hacerlo más extraño en la consola de usuarios si me pone bien quien es el proveedor. He seguido al pie de la letra los tutoriales. Entro normalmente a mi aplicación pero cuando salgo y vuelvo a entrar y pregunto por el usuario si existe como es lógico existe pero no se corresponde ni a  **Google** o **Facebook** por tanto no puede entrar y tengo que volver hacer login.

**Codigo Google:**

```
    // Configure Google Sign In in onCreate()
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

 private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGooogle:" + acct.getId());
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), task -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                    Snackbar.make(snackView, getString(R.string.authentication_failed),
                            BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        throw Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException());
                    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
                        // GooglePlayServices.apk is either old, disabled, or not present
                        // so we need to show the user some UI in the activity to recover.
                        //mActivity.handleException(userRecoverableException);
                        Log.e(TAG, userRecoverableException.getMessage(), userRecoverableException);
                        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(userRecoverableException);
                        MDToast.makeText(context, "Actualice los servicios de Google Play o revise que estén instalados.", MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
                    } catch (GoogleAuthException fatalException) {
                        // Some other type of unrecoverable exception has occurred.
                        // Report and log the error as appropriate for your app.
                        Log.e(TAG, fatalException.getMessage(), fatalException);
                        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(fatalException);
                        MDToast.makeText(context, fatalException.getMessage(), MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                        MDToast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                    assert user != null;

                    askForTypeOfUser(user);
                }
            });
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); // Esto pertenece al de facebook

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {// Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> googleSignInAccountTask = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign-In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = googleSignInAccountTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            if (account != null) {
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            }
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign-In failed
            Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign-In failed:" + CommonStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(e.getStatusCode()));

           }
       }
  }
```

**Código de Facebook:**

```
mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d("LoginFragment", "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);

            String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
            // save accessToken to SharedPreference
            saveAccessToken(accessToken);
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("LoginFragment", "facebook:onCancel");
            loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            animationView.pauseAnimation();

            Snackbar.make(snackView, "Cancelado", BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d("LoginFragment", "facebook:onError");
            loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            animationView.pauseAnimation();
            if (error.toString().equals("CONNECTION_FAILURE: CONNECTION_FAILURE"))
                Snackbar.make(snackView, "Conexión fallida.", BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Snackbar.make(snackView, Objects.requireNonNull(error.getMessage()), BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken) {
    Log.d("LoginFragment", "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + accessToken);

    AuthCredential authCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            //Sign in success, update UI with the signed in user's information
            Log.d("LoginFragment", "signInWithCredential:success");

            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            askForTypeOfUser(user);

        } else {
            loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            animationView.cancelAnimation();
            try {
                throw Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException());
            } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
                switch (e.getErrorCode()) {
                    case "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE":
                        MDToast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.mail_in_use), MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
                        break;
                    case "ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL":
                        MDToast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.account_already_exists), MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
                        break;
                }
            } catch (FacebookServiceException e) {
                Log.w("LoginFragment", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
                MDToast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.connection_error), MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
            } catch (FacebookDialogException e) {
                Log.w("LoginFragment", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
                MDToast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.facebook_error_dialog), MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
            } catch (FacebookAuthorizationException e) {
                Log.w("LoginFragment", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
                MDToast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.fail_auth), MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("LoginFragment", "signInWithCredential:failure");
                MDToast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.connection_error), MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

// Este es el boton que llama a todo lo anterior
facebookAccount.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        animationView.playAnimation();
        if (isOnline(context)) {
                /*loadToast.setText("Logueando con Facebook");
                loadToast.show();*/
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginFragment.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
        } else {
            loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            animationView.pauseAnimation();
            Snackbar.make(v, R.string.bad_connection, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Que es lo que estás tratando de lograr con el providerID? Saber de cuál proveedor te acabas de loguear?

Comment: Si es eso exactamente pero por algún motivo cuando entro usando Google o Facebook me dice que el usuario es firebase y en la consola si me muestra el proveedor adecuado que puede ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre cual es el **problema** exacto del porque pasa eso...

El problema esta en que la sdk de firebase cambio el metodo **.getProviderId()** y ahora retorna siempre ***firebase*** pues es el método de logueo global...

Para poder recuperar con exactitud el tipo de usario por **providerId** tenemos que hacer los siguiente:

> **FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderData().get(1).getProviderId();**

**Explicación:**

> En la posición número uno siempre estará firebase o sea **...get(0).getProviderId()** devuelve siempre firebase, sin embargo en la primera posición devuelve realmente el proveedor que se registro al ingresar el usuario por primera vez.

Espero que esto pueda ayudar a alguien como me ayudo a mi. Salu2